# Windows 7/Vista: change background color of combobox item (or an quivalent feature) when Aero theme is used

Tags: winapi, mfc

`SetBkColor` for combo box item does not works when Aero theme is used on Windows Vista\Windows 7. 
I want to change the background color of my combobox when Aero theme is used. The idea is change the background color of combobox to red to force user to select one of the items available in another window which is launched when one button is clicked.

If not possible then please suggest some optional functionality.

When i am using `SetBkColor` on `OnCtlCOlor` notification of the main window it works on Win XP but not on Windows 7. I am using MFC.

Comment: This is how themed Windows works. If you want to deviate from the theme then you need to paint the control yourself.

Comment: if possible can i have any sample code as i am using MFC after a very very long time.

Comment: Only fill the comboboxes with items that the user is allowed to pick.

Comment: I have create an Owner Draw fixed combobox and implemented DrawItem. (What else  do i need to do?) Still background color is not visible though text color is changed but only for non selected strings.
ALso when Combo is populated through some user action and i go to click the arrow it crashes.